# What am I supposed to present in my Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas

What exactly am I supposed to present when applying for a Schengen visa? I have an invitation letter from my friend in Germany. Will it also be necessary for me to include my bank statement when I have a letter of assistance from my host-friend?

Answer (score 5):

Your friend might be willing to sign a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)). That's much more than a letter, it is a promise to pay the government if you do not leave on schedule. Depending on your friends' income, he might have to post a bond.

Even so, the consular officers will want to know your financial situation to understand your intentions in travelling.

---

**Follow-up:** Germany (or any other Schengen country) will want to know if you are a genuine visitor or an illegal immigrant. The length of stay will not really matter. Once you are in, if only for a day, how do they know that you will leave again?

- Do you have an understandable and documented explanation of who will pay for your visit and why? Even if your friend is going to provide housing and food, the stay in Europe is going to be *expensive*. It would look very bad if you have to borrow money for the flight, because then they question arises how you intend to pay it back.
- Do you have ties to your homeland that make it seem *likely* that you will go home again?

The best answer would be a steady, well-paid job and an account where that salary goes. If you are very young, it would be understandable that you have no account of your own, then you have to explain who pays for your living.

Comment: so what am i to do because i do not have a bank account and im only visiting her for 40 days. So what can i do?

Comment: ok thank you . So if my brother will also provide his bank statement will it be neccessary?

Comment: @leo, is your brother paying for part of the trip? Then you have to explain that and why he does. If he isn't paying then his money won't help. It is a very bad idea to show any money that is not genuinely yours, either earned or from an understandable source.

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly am I supposed to present when applying for a Schengen visa

Here is what you need to supply:

1. Proof that you are returning back. This can be in the form of a job you have, kids or family that is depending on you, a business that you run, etc.
2. A copy of your ticket, itinerary and hotel reservation (if applicable).
3. Your travel documents, that must be valid for 3 months after your intended return + a copy of them.
4. If you are a permanent resident (in other words, not a citizen) proof of permanent residency + copy.
5. Proof that you have funds to cover the costs of the trip that are not being paid for already. So, if your friend is paying for your ticket and hotel (or you are staying with him/her), your friend needs to provide a document stating so. Even if he/she is sponsoring your entire trip, you still need to show a bank statement - as financial history is a good indicator that you are a genuine visitor.
6. One picture, white background.
7. Processing fees.